# Convert time format using sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I want to change format of my files
From: 00:00:**03 006**
to: 00:00:**03,006**

```
sed -i 's/[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]/g' file
```

doesn't work. It find these text but doesn't replace by original numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed -E -i 's/([0-9][0-9]) ([0-9][0-9][0-9])/\1,\2/g' file
```

**Explanation**

When you write

```
[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

in the second part of the `sed` command, you're not saying "replace with the digits you had as input" but "replace with *some* digits", so `sed` can't understand what you want to use as a replacement.

Using regex group (check [this simple explanation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)) will say to `sed` "use the *exact* digits you had as input".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed -ri 's/([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{3})/\1,\2/g' file
```